# Is there a way to add imagePullSecrets to the default ServiceAccount through a Template?

Tags: templates, kubernetes, openshift

I have to add parameterized Secrets to the default ServiceAccount.
I've tried to just add the default ServiceAccount as an object to the Template but that does not seem to do anything.

Or should I just create a new SA inject those Secrets and reference it with useServiceAccount: newSA in the DC?

Thanks!!

Comment: What you mean by `I've tried to just add the default ServiceAccount as an object to the Template but that does not seem to do anything.`? There is kubernetes [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-service-account/#add-imagepullsecrets-to-a-service-account) about that what you want to achieve, have you tried with that? In short you have to create secret with your  docker registry and patch your default service account with your secret name.

Comment: I've missed to add

Comment: So it works after you add your secret to your default service account? I noticed that you use openshift so that [documentation](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.6/openshift_images/managing_images/using-image-pull-secrets.html#images-allow-pods-to-reference-images-from-secure-registries_using-image-pull-secrets) could be more useful.

Comment: What I ended up using was to create a new SA with the template, add the secrets I needed and link the SA to all DC's that needed it. Thank you though!

Answer (score 0):

As @user6242207 mentioned in comments

> What I ended up using was to create a new Service Account with the template, add the secrets I needed and link the Service Account to all DC's that needed it.

---

Just to clarify, there is Kubernetes [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-service-account/#add-imagepullsecrets-to-a-service-account) which describes everything step by step.

1.Create an imagePullSecret

> Create an imagePullSecret, as described in [Specifying ImagePullSecrets](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/images/#specifying-imagepullsecrets-on-a-pod) on a Pod.

```
kubectl create secret docker-registry myregistrykey --docker-server=DUMMY_SERVER \
        --docker-username=DUMMY_USERNAME --docker-password=DUMMY_DOCKER_PASSWORD \
        --docker-email=DUMMY_DOCKER_EMAIL
```

Verify it has been created.

```
kubectl get secrets myregistrykey
```

2.Add image pull secret to service account

> Modify the default service account for the namespace to use this secret as an imagePullSecret.

```
kubectl patch serviceaccount default -p '{"imagePullSecrets": [{"name": "myregistrykey"}]}'
```

> You can instead use kubectl edit, or manually edit the YAML manifests as shown below:

```
kubectl get serviceaccounts default -o yaml > ./sa.yaml
```

3.You can also verify the results

> Now, when a new Pod is created in the current namespace and using the default ServiceAccount, the new Pod has its spec.imagePullSecrets field set automatically:

```
kubectl run nginx --image=nginx --restart=Never
kubectl get pod nginx -o=jsonpath='{.spec.imagePullSecrets[0].name}{"\n"}'
```

The output should be:

```
myregistrykey
```

---

If you use Open Shift then this [documentation](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.6/openshift_images/managing_images/using-image-pull-secrets.html#images-allow-pods-to-reference-images-from-secure-registries_using-image-pull-secrets) could be more useful.